# Remove string of format(':5678"') from a very long string in excel

Tags: excel

I have a very long string in excel. I wnat to remove specific characters only if a specific format exists format is (colon followed by some numbers of any length followed by a double quote). How do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Let us assume your text is in cell A1 and you want to replace "a" by "b":

`=IF(ISERROR(SEARCH(":*a";A1));A1;SUBSTITUTE(A1;"a";"b"))`

Notice that SEARCH can receive the wildcards * and ? whereas FIND cannot.

Comment: In the original question the format was "colon followed by some numbers of any length followed by a" (probably a typo). For the format with the double quote use: =IF(ISERROR(SEARCH(":*""";A1));A1;SUBSTITUTE(A1;"a";"b")) (three double quotes after the other).